# How to optimize BLOB storage in MySQL. while retrieve the records it takes more time

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, blob

How to optimize BLOB storage in MySQL, while retrieving the records it is taking more time

This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE `imageweb` (
      `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `ParcelID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `ImageIndex` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Caption` text,
      `FilePath` varchar(765) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Img` mediumblob,
      `Editor` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `LastModified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      KEY `ID` (`ID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=71 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: use limit syntax while retrieving data from database it will limit the no. of reflected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create indexes in the table, `ImageIndex` and `ParcelID` can be good candidates for indexes as visible from your table structure. Run your queries against the indexed columns, and the table should perform significantly better. Apart from that, the BLOB storage itself is optimized by MySQL on hardware-level.

I though have another suggestion. You can store the image on the Server in a designated path, and store the path along with the file name in DB.